# How to convert string from httpcontet.current.session.getstring to some given type

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, .net-core, httpcontext

In .net 4.8 we are using `HttpContext` like this

`HttpContext.Current.Session["Settings"]) as List<UserSettings>`

but in .net core, it gives an error that Cannot convert string to list.

`_accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Settings")) as List<UserSettings>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .net Core, all session data must be serialized to enable a distributed cache scenario. Complex types must be serialized by the user using another mechanism, such as JSON.

Add the following extension methods to set and get serializable objects:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);

        return value == null ? default(T) : 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Change your code to use the above extension methods.

```
List<Settings> settings = _accessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Settings>>("Settings")
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you get the string first like you are already doing here:
_accessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Settings")) and save it into a variable, and then initialize a list of type string and add it to it afterwards?

Comment: I already tried this but issue still persist.